# SQL Server 2012 - Unable to drop User Defined function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

The following syntax successfully creates a user defined function, but does not drop it. Can anyone identify where my error is?

-- Example 1 - scalar function

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

CREATE FUNCTION Sales.uf_MostRecentCustomerOrderDate (@CustomerID int)
RETURNS
   DATETIME
AS
BEGIN;
    DECLARE @MostRecentOrderDate datetime;

    SELECT @MostRecentOrderDate = MAX(OrderDate)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh
    Where CustomerID = @CustomerID
RETURN @MostRecentOrderDate
END;
GO

-- Using user defined scalar function
SELECT Sales.uf_MostRecentCustomerOrderDate(29825); -- returns 2008-04-01 00:00:00.000 

-- Delete existing scalar valued function
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

-- determines if function exists in database
IF OBJECT_ID (N'Sales.uf_MostRecentCustomerOrderDate', N'IF') IS NOT NULL
    -- deletes function
    DROP FUNCTION Sales.uf_MostRecentCustomerOrderDate;
GO
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Do you have permissions to `CREATE` but not to `DROP` functions?

Comment: No error. Can CREATE and CAN DELETE if I omit IF clause.

Comment: You don´t write the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function gets created with a `type` of `FN` (not `IF` as you've used).

Try this code to drop it:

```
-- determines if function exists in database
IF OBJECT_ID (N'Sales.uf_MostRecentCustomerOrderDate', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    -- deletes function
    DROP FUNCTION Sales.uf_MostRecentCustomerOrderDate;
GO
```

Type `IF` stands for an *inline table-valued function* - this is not the case here.

Type `FN` stands for a scalar function - which this is.

See the [TechNet docs on `sys.objects`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) which also lists all defined types in SQL Server catalog views

Comment: `'N'` is the prefix to show that this string literal is a **Unicode** string (of type `NVARCHAR` or `NCHAR`)

Comment: Thanks, you cleared up the differences nicely. I mistook IF as 'if" not the acronym, 'inline function'.